# Type of 'title' has different optionality than required by protocol 'MKAnnotation'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mapkit, ios9.1

I followed the Ray Wenderlich MapKit tutorial in swift: http://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial and when I created Artwork class I got the error written in the title. I don't know what I have to do.
This is the code:

```
class Artwork: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
let title: String
let locationName: String
let discipline: String
let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

init(title: String, locationName: String, discipline: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.title = title
    self.locationName = locationName
    self.discipline = discipline
    self.coordinate = coordinate

    super.init()
}
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 20):

The anser is in the documentation: we see on the [MKAnnotation protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/MKAnnotation/title) page that the property `title` has to be an Optional.

Which is exactly what the error message is telling you: the optionality of `title` is incorrect.

Change it accordingly:

```
class Artwork: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    var title: String?
    let locationName: String
    let discipline: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(title: String, locationName: String, discipline: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = title
        self.locationName = locationName
        self.discipline = discipline
        self.coordinate = coordinate

        super.init()
    }

}
```

ProTip: in Xcode, CMD+CLICK on your object or definition (`MKAnnotation` in your case) to see how the protocol is declared and what are its requirements.

Answer (score 3):

The MKAnnotation protocol requires title to be an optional type:

```
public protocol MKAnnotation : NSObjectProtocol {

    // Center latitude and longitude of the annotation view.
    // The implementation of this property must be KVO compliant.
    public var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { get }

    // Title and subtitle for use by selection UI.
    optional public var title: String? { get }
    optional public var subtitle: String? { get }
}
```

Just declare you title variable as: `let title: String?` and the problem will go away.

Answer (score 1):

Change it accordingly:

```
var title: String?

var subtitle: String?
```

Answer (score 0):

With addition to the above 
as of 2016 swift 3

if you are following the above tutorial you will need to address the:
    var subtitle: String{
      return locationName }

to : 
    public var subtitle: String?{
        return locationName }

Hope that too clarifies few things